# entity data model - more relation between same tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

when i create my entity data model i have a situation in the DB like this :
      TableFirst : [Id,IdTableSecond,IdTableSecondAgain];TableSecond[Id]

Created data model is: TableFirst.TableSecond  and TableFirst.TableSecond1

Question is: Every time when i create my entity TableFirst.TableSecond will have same relation in behind (IdTableSecond) and TableFirst.TableSecond1 (IdTableSecondAgain)

or they may change?

PS:sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rename the `TableFirst.TableSecond` and `TableFirst.TableSecond1` navigation properties to something meaningful, and whenever you update the model from the database, they will NOT get overriden (you will keep your meaningful names).

Comment: My DB is so big and changes is so often that i can not update, i shuld recreate it.

Comment: Then yes, you do have a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360851/entity-framework-naming-of-model-with-same-types